# Start application using Management API

Tags: android

Using the Android Management API is there a way to start an application that is installed using the following policy, without developing a Custom Device Policy Controller?

```
"applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "{removed for privacy}",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
  }
]
```

In my use case, the application is a background service that monitors the device and needs to be started in order to do so.

Currently, for provisioned devices, the only way to start the application is by using a launch activity to start the service after the device auto installs the application. This requires user interaction on the device.

I am looking for a way to modify the policy above so that the application is started by the system when installed. From what I can see this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is super hacky but I've come up with a solution to start the background service application by using the `persistentPreferredActivities` field in the policy definition. This field sets the default handler for specific Activity intents. It is used for example, and more intended for a Kiosk application to set itself as the home screen on the device.

Using that setting I am able to get the service started by pretending to be the default home screen and then returning to the default home screen when I've completed my work.

```
{
"applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "com.mypackagename",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
    "lockTaskAllowed": true,
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
  }
],
"persistentPreferredActivities": [
    {
      "receiverActivity": "com.mypackagename/.KioskActivity",
      "actions": [
        "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "android.intent.category.HOME",
        "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This follows the recommended policy setup for a kiosk app.

---

I then declare an activity my manifest as so, ( Making it available to be a home screen by filtering for MAIN/HOME ) Also using application pinning, not a necessity:

```
<activity android:name=".KioskActivity"
          android:lockTaskMode="if_whitelisted">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This Activity will be started as the device's home screen after provisioning. I then disable it immediately when it is started after starting my service. This causes the device to go back to its default launcher screen.

My Activity onCreate is as so, to start the service and disable it as the home screen.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    intent.setAction(Intents.SERVICES_ACTION);
    startService(intent);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        stopLockTask();
    }

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, getClass());
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    finish();
}
```